# Trying to create an odd even function

Tags: python, python-2.7

i am trying to create a function where when i call the function it prompts the user to enter an integer and returns whether it is even or odd.
i am trying to make it so that my code prints an error to the console when nothing is entered or when a string is entered, i have gotten it to the point whereby if i enter a number it returns   number, "is an even number" if it is even and    number, "is not an even number" if it is not even here is my code below i am using python 2.7.3

```
def is_even():
    x = int(raw_input("Enter number"))
    if x % 2 == 0:
        return x, "is an even number"
    else:
        return x, "is not an even number"

print is_even()
```

Comment: I'm reasonably sure this code would print an error if one tried to enter a non-number, although this may not be what you are looking for.

Comment: Just saying, wouldn't you want to return it as a one string, not a tuple (`return x, 'is not an even number'` returns two elements, not them combined). You might want to use `return '{} is not an even number'.format(x)`.

Answer (score 6):

You should use a `try`-`except` block:

```
def is_even():
    try:
        x = int(raw_input("Enter an integer: "))  # 'number' != 'integer'
        if x % 2 == 0:
            return x, "is an even number"
        else:
            return x, "is not an even number"
    except ValueError:
        return "Error: You didn't enter an integer!"
```

A `ValueError` will be raised if the input cannot be parsed as an integer on the line `x = int(...)`, in which case we reach the bottom return statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`isdigit()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) method before casting to int:

```
def is_even():
    x = raw_input("Enter number")
    if x.isdigit():
        if int(x) % 2 == 0:
            return x, "is an even number"
        else:
            return x, "is not an even number"
    else:
        return x, "is not an int"
```

Comment: What about negative integers?

Comment: @DSM True, to be honest I haven't thought about that. I suppose `x.startswith("-") and x[1:].isdigit()` can solve that; however my solution is just an alternative to @A.R.S.'s one, which I also think that is better than mine's.